# Groups Migration API returning invalid token...from OAuth2 Playground

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-groups-migration

I'm trying write a script that migrates old emails over to a Google group.  I've been hammering out a request in Google's OAuth2 Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/, but I keep getting a 401 error that's caused by and invalid_token.

From the playground, I selected the groups migration API (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.migration), got an authorization code, and swapped it for an access_token. So it *seemed* like everything was going well.  Then I made a did a POST request to this URL.

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/groups/v1/groups/TEST_GROUP@googlegroups.com/archive?uploadType=media`

I've got the following two headers:

`Content-Type :   message/rfc822
uploadType :    media`

I should get an error about having some missing info in header, but instead I get I get an auth error.

`HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Alternate-protocol: 443:quic,p=0.002
Content-length: 251
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
Server: UploadServer ("Built on Sep 18 2014 17:00:06 (1411084806)")
Date: Fri, 26 Sep 2014 15:56:13 GMT
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401, 
    "message": "Authorization Failed", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "locationType": "header", 
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Authorization Failed", 
        "reason": "authError", 
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }`

I gave auth consent while signed into the email that is the admin of the google groups account I've created.

Any idea what I'm going wrong?

Edit: added header info and specifier where I'm making this request for (URL for Google's Oauth playground)

Comment: from where did you make the POST, and can you copy the POST request URL and headers into the question.

Comment: I'm making the post from Google's own OAuth playground.  I've update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a consumer Google Group (email address is @googlegroups.com) or is it a Google Group that is a part of a Google Apps domain? (@yourcompany.com)

Note that the API only works for Google Groups for Business. You must authenticate as a Google Apps Super Admin user and be POSTing to a Google Groups for Business group (doesn't end in @googlegroups.com). These requirements are [spelled out in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/guides/prerequisites).